# Extracting a value from split in python

Tags: python

```
id,  name, assignment#,  grade
[1, 'james', '1,', 18.0]
[2, 'alice', '1,', 19.0]
[5, 'jorgen', '1,', 19.8]
[1, 'james', '2,', 19.5]
[2, 'alice', '2,', 22.75]
[3, 'kevin', '2,', 24.75]
[4, 'george', '2,', 23.5]
[5, 'jorgen', '2,', 12.5]
[3, 'kevin', '1,', 15.6]
[4, 'george', '1,', 18.4]
[3, 'kevin', '4,', 18.0]
[4, 'george', '4,', 28.5]
[5, 'jorgen', '4,', 7.5]
[1, 'james', '3,', 21.75]
[2, 'alice', '3,', 25.0]
[3, 'kevin', '3,', 21.25]
[4, 'george', '3,', 18.75]
[5, 'jorgen', '3,', 11.5]
[1, 'james', '4,', 29.4]
[2, 'alice', '4,', 29.4]
```

This is the split data I have, and I am trying to add the grades and output (id, name, grade).  How can I do this? i am supposed to output

```
1, james: 88.65
2, alice: 96.15
3, kevin: 79.6
4, george: 89.15
5, jorgen: 51.3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add the grades and output"? Add to what?

Comment: as you can see there are 4 assignments for each student and the last box is the marks and if i add those 4 for each student, that should give them a final mark.

Comment: so for james, output is supposed  to be    1, james: 88.65   and so on. but i have to assume the number of students are arbitrary, so i need to use some kind of loop, but i am stuck here

Comment: This is not an appropriate data structure for these data. The `list` type is best used on homogeneous data. You might want to look into dictionaries or objects.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a matrix:

```
M = [[1, 'james', '1,', 18.0],
[2, 'alice', '1,', 19.0],
[5, 'jorgen', '1,', 19.8],
[1, 'james', '2,', 19.5],
[2, 'alice', '2,', 22.75],
[3, 'kevin', '2,', 24.75],
[4, 'george', '2,', 23.5],
[5, 'jorgen', '2,', 12.5],
[3, 'kevin', '1,', 15.6],
[4, 'george', '1,', 18.4],
[3, 'kevin', '4,', 18.0],
[4, 'george', '4,', 28.5],
[5, 'jorgen', '4,', 7.5],
[1, 'james', '3,', 21.75],
[2, 'alice', '3,', 25.0],
[3, 'kevin', '3,', 21.25],
[4, 'george', '3,', 18.75],
[5, 'jorgen', '3,', 11.5],
[1, 'james', '4,', 29.4],
[2, 'alice', '4,', 29.4]]

grades_for_james =sum([row[3] for row in M if row[1]=='james' ])
```

Comment: how i got those data is i opened a text file and did readlines() and split. so it is not a matrix. thank you for your comment though!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`defaultdict(float)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to accumulate grades:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grades = defaultdict(float)
for id, name, assignment, grade in data:
    grades[id, name] += grade

# Now output (in order by id to be nice)
for id_name, total in sorted(id_grades.items()):
    id, name = id_name
    print('%d, %s: %.2f' % (id, name, total))
```